# No results behavior in Views not working when referencing another field after cache clear

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

**My Setup:**

I am using Drupal 7.41 and Views / Views UI 3.11.

1. I have a taxonomy named *sermon series* that includes a field called *series image*.
2. I have a content type called *sermons* that has an image called *sermon image* and a term reference to the *sermon series* taxonomy.
3. Lastly, I have a View called *sermons* that:

   - pulls in the most recent 1 node from the content type *sermons*
   - has a relationship to the taxonomy *sermon series*
   - has the first field in the *fields* list as the **sermon series image** (from taxonomy) and is set to "hide from display". The *replacement pattern token* for this field is [field_sermon_image_2]
   - has the second field in the *fields* list as the **sermon image** (from content type) and is set to show in the display.

     - this field has a *no results behavior* set to the token [field_sermon_image_2]

**Expected Behavior:**

If the most recent node has an image associated with it, that image will show. If there is no image associated with the node, it will show the image associated with the taxonomy *sermon series*.

**Actual Behavior**

When I create a node **with** the *sermon image* filled out, everything works as expected and the view shows the sermon image associated with the Node shows.

When I create a node **without** a sermon image filled out, the view correctly shows the *sermon series image* associated with the taxonomy *sermon series*.

Here's where it gets weird. If I create a node **without** a sermon image filled out, see the view correctly show the *sermon series image* from the taxonomy, then either clear cache or wait until cache expires, no image shows up at all. I know the fallback is working correctly as even the [field_sermon_image_2] has a *no results behavior* fallback to a *generic* image and that's what always shows up.

Through some testing, I found that unpublishing the node, viewing the *view*, then re-publishing the node will bring the correct image back (at least until the next cache flush).

I'm not sure where to look for this odd behavior. It seems like I have everything setup correctly in my view as I can get the correct images to show up, I just can't get them to show up consistently.

Any advice you can give would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Does this happen when you are login as Admin or is this only for anonymous users?

Comment: @no-sssweat in testing, it seems that roles don't play a part whether it's administrator or anonymous that initiates the cache.

Comment: If you inspect the element with your browser where the image is suppose to be does it show anything?

Comment: No, it's empty. I've tested that by setting a fallback image for the "sermon series image" it falls back to that so there are three levels:
Sermon Image --> Sermon Series Image ---> Default Image. Where I expect "sermon series image" to show up, the default image shows.

Answer (score 0):

I replicated your scenario and its working fine for me.

Here is what I did.

1. In Taxonomy I added a **Vocabulary** called "**Sermons**", I added an **image
   field** called "**tax image**"
2. I added a **term name** of "**Mega Man**" to Sermons, and **uploaded a
   mega man picture** to the "**tax image**" field.
3. Created an **Article** with title of "**Enter Shikari is awesome**" which has "Article Picture" as a field and I **uploaded a picture of the band**. Term Ref "Mega Man"
4. I Created another **Article** with title "**Woooo**" this time **I did not upload any image** to the "Article Picture" field. Term Ref "Mega Man"

**Now in Views**

5. In **FILTER CRITERIA** I added **Content Type** Is one of **Article** (so it only shows Article nodes)
6. In **RELATIONSHIP** I added **Content: Taxonomy terms on node**

   - Check marked "Sermon Series"
   - Check marked **Require this relationship**.

[image]

7. In **FIELDS** and I added the "**tax image**"

   - checked **exclude from display**.
8. In **FIELDS** I added "**Article Picture**"

   - No Results behaviour I put the token [field_tax_image]

[image]

9. I put a cache of 1 hour.

**So here is what my View looks like**

[image]

10. I added another **Article** with title "**Kewl its working!!!**" with Term Ref "Mega Man" and **left the "Article Picture" field empty.**
11. **I Cleared the cache** (since my view is cached, it won't show "kewl is working!!! until I clear it).

**RESULT AS EXPECTED** `Kewl its working!!!` and `Wooo` do `not have Article Pictures`, so Mega Man (tax image) shows up.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! I have spent the last 3 hours comparing yours to mine, recreating mine to match yours & the only difference was making relationship required was missing on mine. Unfortunately my results are now all over the board. Saving, un/publishing, republishing yields completely different and unpredictable results. Sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't. Sometimes it works 20 times in a row, sometimes it breaks 20 times in a row. Other times it's 1 here or 2 there. I'm going to keep trying and I'll let you know what I find but wanted to thank you for your response!

Comment: **making relationship required** only shows Articles that have a term ref. If you still want to show Articles that don't have a term ref, then uncheck require box. Just know that if you then create an Article with no image and no term ref, then the view would not show an image because it doesn't have anything to work with (no article pic, no term ref).

Comment: When you create a view by default **FILTER CRITERIA** has **Content Published (Yes)**. So if you unpublished a node, it will not show up in the view. **If you want unpublished nodes to show up** you need to **REMOVE** `Content Published (Yes)`